# jQuery datepicker doesn't update the value in sessionStorage

Tags: html, datepicker

I am working with calendars, where the user must enter a date to search within the database. My problem is in sessionStorage, as they are not updated as I change the date.

JS

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#calendario").datepicker();
            $('#calendario').change(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                $('#dataE').text(val);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div>
   <p>Data Específica: <input type="text" id="calendario" name="dateE" /></p>
     <script>
        $(function (){
           sessionStorage.setItem("spcDate", $('#calendario').datepicker().val());
           console.log("Data especifica: " + spcDate);
        });
     </script>
     <span id="dataE"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `spcDate` would undefined variable, i think, you should use `console.log("Data especifica: " +sessionStorage.getItem('spcDate'))`??

Comment: Yes, I did it. But my problem is on in the storage. The value of my variables doesn't updated.

Comment: `sessionStorage` is keep value in current login(browser tab), you can't retrieve value in new tab, and no longer exist after close browser. you should use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`

Comment: FYI: `localStorage` is similar to `sessionStorage`, except that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends

Comment: Hmm. I understand. But I don't need the data to be stored, it will be used for research only.

Comment: Ok then you should not have issue.

Comment: you set the sessionstorage once on page load, then you never set it again. How do you expect to update the value in sessionstorage?